# Minimum privileges to run a rails db migration with PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I enrolled into a web-host plan so I could have my rails apps published. They provided me with a server and access to it. This is a shared CentOS Linux server and I can access its bash.

I was trying to load my database schema into the postgres database (v8.4) they are offering but it gives me an error when doing so.
When I execute:

```
 RAILS_ENV=production rake db:schema:load
```

The following error is generated:

```
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXTENSION"
LINE 1: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "plpgsql"
               ^
: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "plpgsql"
/home/user/path-to-app/db/schema.rb:17:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/user/path-to-app/db/schema.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXTENSION"
LINE 1: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "plpgsql"
               ^
/home/user/path-to-app/db/schema.rb:17:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/user/path-to-app/db/schema.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Because the web-host provider does not allow many db privileges, and due to my unfamiliarity with PostgreSQL, I would prefer a solution changing something on the rails side...

Is there something I can do on the rails side to work around (or hopefully address) this issue?

If nothing can be really done from the rails side I would have to be specific with the privileges necessary.

This PostgreSQL [EXTENSION object](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createextension.html) seems to demand privileges my db user does not have...

What would be the minimum privileges for the rails database user running the db migration in PostgeSQL?

### Update

This is about PostgreSQL 8.4, witch according to the comments here do not have the "CREATE EXTENSION" command.

Comment: `CREATE EXTENSION` was introduced with Postgres 9.1

Comment: that is a relief... should i downgrade the pg gem?

Comment: it's is not about the `pg` gem, it's all about Postgres database itself. `pg` gem it's just the ruby wrapper for `Postgres` database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can only a superuser CREATE EXTENSION hstore, but not on Heroku?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723100/why-can-only-a-superuser-create-extension-hstore-but-not-on-heroku)

Comment: Also related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410631/how-to-solve-privileges-issues-when-restore-postgresql-database

Comment: why you just do not do the migration? `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: I understand that Зелёный, but there is nothing i can do with the db server itself.... is there nothing i can do on rails side?

Comment: OK... the `rake db:migrate` command did it (some many other errors happened in this adventure with his provider that i even forgot to go simple) if you wish I can mark your answer as solution.

Comment: Your hosting provider should provide a less prehistoric version of PostgreSQL. If this is a new app deployment then it's absurd to use 8.4. It'd be like designing a new app to run on Windows XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CREATE EXTENSION` was introduced with Postgres 9.1, i suggest you to run migrations:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
```