# Creating a PostgreSQL database backup via psql on macOS

Tags: django, postgresql, psql

I'm trying to create a PostgreSQL *local* db dump via Terminal on macOS using **psql**. My next step is to [upload/import my entire db to my Amazon RDS PostgreSQL db instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html).

Can anyone help me with the Terminal command to create a dump file 'mydbdump.sql' for my 'mydb' database. I've sorted through existing questions, searched forums (tried [similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311692/migrate-postgres-dump-to-rds)), even Amazon RDS docs (above, link), and am having no luck with the commands from any of these docs. What am I doing wrong?

**Here is what I've tried so far (and I've gotten nothing back, not even an error):**

**Via sudo:**

```
sudo -u postgres psql pg_dump -Fc -o -f /Users/<my_computer>/database_backup.sql mydb
```

**Via psql, connected to mydb (`\c mydb;`):**

**mydb-#** `pg_dump dbname=mydb -f mydbdump.sql`

**mydb-#** `pg_dump -U postgres -W -F t mydb > /Users/<my_computer>/database_backup.sql`

**mydb-#** `pg_dump -Fc mydb > /Users/<my_computer>/database_backup.sql`

**mydb-#** `pg_dump -U postgres mydb > database_backup.sql`

**mydb-#** `pg_dump -Fc mydb > /Users/<my_computer>/database_backup.sql`

**mydb-#** `pg_dump -U postgres -W -F t mydb > /Users/<my_computer>/database_backup.sql`

**For reference:**
I'm using Django, in *settings.py*:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'dbuser',
        'PASSWORD': '<MYPASSWORD>',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

By the way, my Django app is running successfully.

When I list all database relations in *mydb*:

```
\dt mydb;
```

**Output:**

```
List of relations
 Schema |            Name            | Type  | Owner  
--------+----------------------------+-------+--------
 public | auth_group                 | table | dbuser
 public | auth_group_permissions     | table | dbuser
 public | auth_permission            | table | dbuser
 public | auth_user                  | table | dbuser
 public | auth_user_groups           | table | dbuser
 public | auth_user_user_permissions | table | dbuser
 public | django_admin_log           | table | dbuser
 public | django_content_type        | table | dbuser
 public | django_migrations          | table | dbuser
 public | django_session             | table | dbuser
 public | polls_choice               | table | dbuser
 public | polls_question             | table | dbuser
(12 rows)
```

When I list all schemas in psql:

```
select s.nspname as table_schema,
       s.oid as schema_id,  
       u.usename as owner
from pg_catalog.pg_namespace s
join pg_catalog.pg_user u on u.usesysid = s.nspowner
order by table_schema;
```

**Output:**

```
table_schema    | schema_id |  owner   
--------------------+-----------+----------
 information_schema |     13337 | postgres
 pg_catalog         |        11 | postgres
 pg_temp_1          |     12314 | postgres
 pg_toast           |        99 | postgres
 pg_toast_temp_1    |     12315 | postgres
 public             |      2200 | postgres
```

Comment: you dont run pg_dump inside psql

Answer (score 4):

First running pg_dump inside psql will not work.

Second, this:

```
sudo -u postgres psql pg_dump -Fc -o -f /Users/<my_computer>/database_backup.sql mydb
```

is a variation of the first thing. You want:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump -Fc -f /Users/<my_computer>/database_backup.sql mydb
```

`pg_dump` is a client program by itself.

NOTE: No `-o`. There is `-O` which is for no-owner.

See examples at bottom of this page:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html

Lastly are you sure this doesn't get you an error?:

```
test(5432)=# pg_dump dbname=mydb -f mydbdump.sql;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_dump"
LINE 1: pg_dump dbname=mydb -f mydbdump.sql;
```

If not then I would check your logging settings in postgresql.conf.

Comment: Aha, thank you. I did not know pg_dump was a program. Then regarding "/Users/<my_computer>/database_backup.sql" > I was specifying the path on my computer to save my .sql file, is this accurate? I ask because since your answer, I found my "pg_dump" is located here: /usr/local/bin/pg_dump.

Comment: Yes whatever is after ```-f``` will be where the file is saved. There are plenty of examples at the page I linked to.

Comment: Thank you!! This is the command that finally worked: 
sudo -u postgres pg_dump mydb > db.sql
> computer password 
> postgres password

Answer (score 1):

**This is the command that finally worked:**

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump mydb > db.sql
```

**This prompted me for:**

- my *computer* password
- then my *postgres* password

I did not need to specify any additional paths. The db.sql file automatically saved to my root directory.

Comment: Yes the computer user does the sudo  and the user postgres does the dump.
Just know the the above created a plain text dump file and you will need to use psql not pg_restore to restore it.

Comment: Understood on pg_restore, thank you again for your help Adrian.