# ERM from PostgreSQL via psql (SQL Shell)

Tags: postgresql, psql, entity-relationship

I need to understand the relations between tables in a PostgreSQL database. I will not have the ability to download pgAdmin4 like I am used to working in. So after looking around I found `pg_dump.exe` built into PostgreSQL. I thought I could just do something like this in the SQL Shell (psql) to get a dump of the database and then have the ability to upload it into another system:

```
database=# pg_dump database > path/to/save/file.sql;
```

Based on the docs >> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-pgdump.html

But when I run that I get an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_dump"
LINE 1: pg_dump database > path/to/save/file.sql;
        ^
```

I saw on this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62565006/creating-a-postgresql-database-backup-via-psql-on-macos) was similar to my issue with the `pg_dump` error. In the solutions, [Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver) says that `pg_dump` does not work within psql. When I run the code that Adrian suggested, I also get an error.
Any thoughts on how I can use psql to get the information that I need of this database?

Note: I am accessing a Linux VM on a Windows machine.

Comment: `pg_dump` is a program that you use within the Windows terminal, not within `psql`.  If you want to see relationships between tables, use the `\d` command within `psql`

Comment: @richyen 1) `pg_dump` works in many terminals, not only with Windows console. 2) It is possible to execute an external program directly from the `psql` using `\!` meta-command: `\! pg_dump`

Comment: Why *are* you trying to use `pg_dump` from within `psql` if you already that's not how it works?

Comment: @Bergi I found out that doesn't work after searching my error. Hence the post.

Comment: @richyen I thought that `\d` only gave the columns and data types etc, but not how those columns are related to other table columns?

Comment: @Abelisto is correct, though I am strictly making statements in regards to this post.  If `\d` will give columns and such.  If you want to see foreign key relationships, please use `\d+`

Comment: thanks @richyen, I was hoping for a less manual way than going though each table. But it will get the job done.

Comment: If you are looking for foreign key relationships, then you can find that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152260/postgres-sql-to-list-table-foreign-keys.  From your original post, it sounded like you were trying to get `pg_dump` working so you knew the table structure.  A caveat--if the tables are defined without foreign key constraints, you will not be able to understand the relationships even with `\d`